# Grid system in bootstrap v4 not working on iPhone 5s (iOS 9)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iphone-5, twitter-bootstrap-4

The grid system is not working on both Google Chrome and Safari on iPhone 5s with iOS 9 installed.

We are using Bootstrap v4 alpha-6 SASS version with including only files we need. Website works on all other devices - Desktop, laptops, tablets (iPad and Android) and other mobile phones (Android, Windows Phone, iPhone 6 with iOS 10).

- Operating system: iPhone 5s (iOS 9)
- Browser: both Safari and Chrome
- Website: https://www.poljinos.hr/en/

The problem is with grid system, it is displaying all col-* items in one row and website is more then 100% wide.

Any suggestions why this is happening ?

Comment: can you please attach partial or entire code of a page? Or at least attach some images showing the expected behavior and the actual behavior? Because using the chrome dev tools and setting to responsive IPhone 5, it appeared to work well here

Comment: Yes, please add a [mcve] to your question

Comment: And beware that flexbox support in Safari has a few known issues (specially Safari 10 and below) even in mobile: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox